# How to auto-complete "hashcat" options?

Tags: command-line, autocomplete

Is it possible to get auto-completion of `hashcat` command line options? What I mean is, when entering, for example, `hashcat --incre`, and then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I want that the incomplete option completed to `--increment`.

I'm using Arch Linux, Hashcat v6.2.6 and GNOME Terminal 3.46.8.

Comment: It indeed doesn't autocomplete the options. If you're using `bash`, the `complete` command might help you achieve this. See https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command